# Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. with cdf $F(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha\left[1-F(x)\right]=b$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Problem:** Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution function $F(x)$. Denote the maximum of the first $n$ elements by $M_n$. Show that if
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x^\alpha\left[1-F(x)\right]=b$$
with fixed positive constants $\alpha,b$ then $n^{-1/\alpha}M_n$ converges in distribution and identify the limiting distribution.

**What I have so far:** Put $Y_n=n^{-1/\alpha}M_n$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
F_{Y_n}(x)
&=P\left(\max_{1\leq k\leq n}X_k\leq n^{1/\alpha}x\right)\\
&=[F(xn^{1/\alpha})]^n\\
&=[1-P(X_1>xn^{1/\alpha})]^n\\
&=\left[1-\frac{x^\alpha n}{x^\alpha n}P(X_1>xn^{1/\alpha})\right]^n.
\end{align*}
Now I need to evaluate the limit above. It seems to me that this limit evaluates to $e^{-b/x^\alpha}$, but upon graphing this function, I note that it is not a valid CDF. Therefore, this cannot be the right answer.

---

Could anyone help with a hint on how to evaluate the limit above rigorously?
Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you have finished all the necessary work( except a typo in the end).
And $F(x)=e^{-b/x^{\alpha}}$ is obviously an acceptable CDF( for $\alpha>0$).
Note that: $F(x)=0$ when $x \le 0$

Comment: This question might sound uninformed, but may ask why is it that we have $F(x)=0$ when $x\leq0$?

Comment: Firstly, I think you are bugged because we don't have the same limit for $ x \le 0$, but you see, when $x \le 0$ we don't have $ xn^{1/\alpha} \rightarrow +\infty$. Secondly, regarding why $F(x)= 0 $ for $x \le 0$, I think this also is easy for you. Yet you may have been lost in your thought.

Comment: That's because $$ 0 \le \mathbb{P}( Y_n \le x ) \le \mathbb{P}( M_n \le 0 )=\mathbb{P}(X_1 \le 0)^n \rightarrow 0$$ Because $P(X_1>0)>0$

Comment: Thank you, now I understand!